# SurfFeatureDetector and creating an empty mask with Mat()

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, surf

I would like to use `SurfFeatureDetector` to detect keypoints on specifying area of a picture:

1. Train_pic & Source_pic
2. Detect Train_pic keypoint_1 using `SurfFeatureDetector`.
3. Detect Source_pic keypoint_2 using `SurfFeatureDetector` in specifying area.
4. Compute and match.

OpenCV `SurfFeatureDetector` as below.

`void FeatureDetector::detect(const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat())`

**mask** – Mask specifying where to look for keypoints (optional). Must be a char matrix with non-zero values in the region of interest.

Any one can helps to explain how to create `mask=Mat()` for Source_pic?

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 4):

You don't technically have to specify the empty matrix to use the `detect` function as it is the default parameter.

You can call `detect` like this:

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;
detector->detect(anImage, keyPoints);
```

Or, by explicitly creating the empty matrix:

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;
detector->detect(anImage, keyPoints, Mat());
```

If you want to create a mask in a region of interest, you could create one like this:

Assuming `Source_pic` is of type `CV_8UC3`,

```
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(Source_pic.size(), Source_pic.type());

// select a ROI
Mat roi(mask, Rect(10,10,100,100));

// fill the ROI with (255, 255, 255) (which is white in RGB space);
// the original image will be modified
roi = Scalar(255, 255, 255);
```

**EDIT :** Had a copy-pasta error in there. Set the ROI for the `mask`, and then pass that to the `detect` function.

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Hi Mevatron,

I tried set the ROI to white color.
I want to detect keypoints only inside the ROI instead of whole source pic.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: @Jay Hey Jay! See my edited response. You essentially just create a mask with non-zero values where you want `detect` it to run.

Comment: When I try to set a mask as described above then I get this error: "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mask.empty() || (mask.type() == CV_8UC1 && mask.size() == image.size())) in detect, file /Users/users/Downloads/OpenCV-iOS/OpenCV-iOS/../opencv-svn/modules/features2d/src/detectors.cpp, line 63"

Comment: OpenCV is telling you that either the mask provided is not empty, the mask type is not CV_8UC1, or the mask is not the same size as the processed image. Make sure you have all those things set correctly.